# How to write DTD to constrain multiple IDREF values in a string?

Tags: xml, dtd

```
<Course Number="CS105A" Prerequisites="CS101A" Instructors="JC XX" Enrollment="610">
  <Title>Programming XXX</Title>
  <Description>Abstraction and its relation to programming.</Description>
</Course>

<Course Number="CS106B" Prerequisites="CS106A" Instructors="JC ER" Enrollment="620">
  <Title>Programming Abstractions</Title>
  <Description>Abstraction and its relation to programming.</Description>
</Course>

<Course Number="CS107" Prerequisites="CS106B CS105A" Instructors="JZ" Enrollment="500">
  <Title>Computer Organization and Systems</Title>
  <Description>Introduction to the fundamental concepts of computer systems.</Description>
</Course>
```

How to write the `ATTLIST` spec for the `Prerequisites` attribute which can be composed of multiple ID values such as `"CS106B CS105A"`?  Would the following work?

```
<!ATTLIST Course Number ID #REQUIRED>
<!ATTLIST Course Prerequisites IDREF #IMPLIED>
```

Comment: This is from Jennifer Widom's databases class. Homework!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One can use [`IDREFS`](http://www.w3schools.com/dtd/dtd_attributes.asp) if the value of the attribute (`Prerequisites`) is a list of `ID` values as written as a joined string with a white space character as delimiter, i.e. `id1 id2`:

```
<ATTLIST Course Number ID #REQUIRED>
<ATTLIST Course Prerequisites IDREFS #IMPLIED>
```

One can [validate a DTD against an XML online](http://www.validome.org/grammar/).

Answer (score 2):

Like Meng Lu said, you should use [IDREFS](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-attribute-types) (different link).

You also don't need to have separate attribute declarations (`ATTLIST`) for each attribute in an element.

You're also missing a very important `!` in your declaration.

Example:

```
<!ATTLIST Course 
          Number        ID     #REQUIRED
          Prerequisites IDREFS #IMPLIED>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the DTD exercises for the current free online 'Intro to DBs' course @ Stanford (http://class2go.stanford.edu/db/Winter2013/interactive_exercises/DTDExercises).

As pointed out, it's easy to run this on your own. I run it against xmllint, for example, and xmllint tells me if my DTD doesn't pass. I follow the error trails until it does pass, then turn that in as my answer for this question (#3 in the referenced set).